# Send a text file delimited tab with webclient

Tags: .net, vb.net, vbscript

I am trying to send a file delimited with tab with webclient.
 But I have a error when trying upload the file:

> (the remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request)

How could I upload the file ?

This is the url request

Example Request:

```
POST /v1/orders/confirm/ HTTP/1.1
Host: file-api.fillz.com
X-FillZ-Access-Key: EXAMPLEACCESSKEY
X-FillZ-Date: 20141118T222611Z
X-FillZ-Signature: ced6826de95e2bfadd8f937f0ac708e8669e98d4c0145114c84f54174ace327b
Content-Type: application/tab-delimited

_content: 'order-id     status
           1000 shipped'
```

```vb
messageBody = "C:\Temp\Fillz\2015-02-09-09-51-34_proc_file_fillz.tab"
request.ContentType = "application/tab-delimited"
Dim contentType As String = "application/tab-delimited"
Dim myWebClient As New System.Net.WebClient()
myWebClient.Headers.Add("X-FillZ-Date", timeStamp)
myWebClient.Headers.Add("X-FillZ-Access-Key", accessKey)
myWebClient.Headers.Add("X-FillZ-Signature", signature)
Try
   Dim client As New WebClient()
   Dim responseBinary() As Byte = client.UploadFile(uri, messageBody)
   Dim response As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBinary)
   Catch ex As Exception
      Return "Exception " & ex.ToString()
End Try
```

Comment: I think you should use a registered MIME-type rather than one you made up (I could not find "application/tab-delimited" in an official list: [Media types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#application)). The closest fit would be "text/plain".

Comment: Are you saying that the "Example Request" is what you need (regardless of not using a registered MIME type)? If so, you should be using `myWebClient` for the upload, not a new instance (`client`) of a WebClient. And don't forget to do `myWebClient.Dispose()` in a `Finally` block so that it frees any resources it is using.